# Set rule set for <p><a>...</a></p> according to the href target

Tags: javascript, less

I'm working with a sophisticated LESS-based template in a CMS that we must use for (good) commercial reasons.  I want to be able to give a different ruleset based on the URL referenced in href (which I can use to distinguish between my site's document store and other locations) WITHOUT having to class the tags - because non-technical editors aren't reliable class-setters.

LESS, of which I have only beginner's knowledge, seems not to be able to do this: is this right?  If it is, is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS just generates CSS. CSS supports [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

```
a[href="http://example.com"] {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: [Worth taking a look at the MDN docs too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). If you want to target just a hostname, for example: `a[href^="http://example.com"]`